# How to delete lines not containing certain text from a long text file (possibly over 70 000 lines) using batch

Tags: batch-file, text-files

I have a long text file (possibly over 70 000 lines) which i need to change - deleting some lines and changing some others. What is the right batch command?

I have this text file:

```
blah
blah_blah, blah_other_blah
NUMLINES,     71369
VARIABLE_TYPES,T1,T10,S
!,NUMBER,OTHER
*,"1421915957",3
*,"1422222863",7
*,"1422239294",4
*,"1422382002",10
*,"1422485177",4
*,"1422496045",8
*,"1422500174",10
*,"1422500175",8

and so on

*,"1930482159",10
*,"1930482160",3
*,"1930482161",3

## some other blah lines
blah
```

And I want to have this one:

```
NUMBER;OTHER
1421915957;3
1422222863;7
1422239294;4
1422382002;10
1422485177;4
1422496045;8
1422500174;10
1422500175;8

and so on

1930482159;10
1930482160;3
1930482161;3
```

Thanks for your help.

So Far, I tried deleting the unwanted lines with this code:

```
findstr /v /b /c:"*," file1.txt > file2.txt

findstr /x /v /l /G:"file1.txt" "file2.txt" > "file3.txt"
```

But it exits with search string to long

Comment: Can you provide any code you have tried so far?

Comment: what is your second `findstr` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `findstr` to get all lines that start either with `!,` or with `*,`. Put a `for /f` loop around to extract the desired information and redirect the output to a new file:

```
(for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=," %%a in ('type file.txt ^|findstr /b /c:"!," /c:"*,"') do @echo %%~b,%%c)>file2.txt
```

The `~` in `%%~b` will remove the surrounding quotes.

(Note: this is batch file syntax. If you want to execute it directly on command line, replace every `%%` with a single `%`)

(I hope, none of your `blah` lines start with `!,` or `*,`)